# What is this variable "RlsSvcPort" in my System environment variable?

Tags: windows-10, security, environment-variables

I was checking my environment variables to make some dev-related changes and found this:

[image: Suspicious Looking Environment Variable]

What can it be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What is this variable "RlsSvcPort" in my System environment variable?

> RlsSvcPort (22112) is used by the Sage Licensing Service, which is a licensing and activation service for Sage software products.

Source: [i found out ports in my environment that i'm suspicious on them, - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/i-found-out-ports-in-my-environment-that-im/1004fea7-cc08-42c0-a167-7eca8e3d5e0b)